# Как в C# написать лямбда-выражение, пример внутри

Tags: c#, lambda, делегаты

Как записать вот для такого:

```
Func<int, Func<int, Func<int, int, int>, int>, int> func3;
```

какое-нибудь выражение полностью?

Проблема с пониманием того, как именно эти вложенные делегаты писать и применять, вплоть до последнего.

Comment: Мораль: не используйте `Func` для всего подряд :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь понять выражение целиком, а не разбить его на части.

Давайте лучше смотреть по частям.

`Func<int, int, int>` — это функция, которая получает на вход 2 аргумента типа `int`, и возвращает `int`. Наподобие такого:

```
Func<int, int, int> f1 = (x, y) => x + y;
```

Чтобы не ломать голову, введём обозначение:

```
using BinaryFunction = Func<int, int, int>;
```

Далее: `Func<int, Func<int, int, int>, int>` — то же, что `Func<int, BinaryFunction, int>`. Функция, которая берёт аргументами `int` и `BinaryFunction`, и возвращает `int`. Например:

```
Func<int, BinaryFunction, int> f2 = (a, f) => f(a, a);
```

Эту функцию тоже надо обозначить:

```
using IntAndBinaryFuncToInt = Func<int, Func<int, int, int>, int>;
```

(Хотя, возможно, есть название *по смыслу*.)

Ну и в конце-концов третья функция берёт `int` и функцию типа `IntAndBinaryFuncToInt`, и возвращает `int`. Например:

```
Func<int, IntAndBinaryFuncToInt, int> func3 = (u, f) => u;
```

---

Кстати, вам не обязательно нужна лямбда. Например:

```
int F(int u, IntAndBinaryFuncToInt f)
{
    return u;
}

Func<int, IntAndBinaryFuncToInt, int> func3 = F;
```

Answer (score 4):

Подходит, например, такое выражение:

```
Func<int, Func<int, Func<int, int, int>, int>, int> func3 = (i, f) => f(i, (a, b) => a + b);
```

Comment: Спасибо, именно так делал, но со скобками ошибся вконце... не мог разобраться, как это записывать нужно.